# flattened pom is not being used?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3, pom.xml

It is a multi-module maven project.  I have included flatten-maven-plugin in my parent pom

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta-2</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
```

defined a property scl_version in parent pom and used ${scl_version} in  of child pom. Value is **0.0.1** .

when i run ***mvn flatten:flatten***

It generates a warning :
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant.

A flattened pom is created in all modules including parent and all the childs.

Flattened pom has value of the property in ***version*** tag of child pom. But when i give, mvn install it still gives warning that version should be constant but it is an expression.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

But documentation says:

> This MOJO realizes the goal flatten that generates the flattened POM
>   and potentially updates the POM file so that the current
>   MavenProject's file points to the flattened POM instead of the
>   original pom.xml file. The flattened POM is a reduced version of the
>   original POM with the focus to contain only the important information
>   for consuming it. Therefore information that is only required for
>   maintenance by developers and to build the project artifact(s) are
>   stripped.

so when i do mvn install it should not generate warning.

mvn install and mvn flatten:flatten both generates this warning:

[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant.

Am i missing something, is it not using flattened-pom.xml.
Do i need to specify something.

PARENT POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.a.b</groupId>
<artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>ABC</name>
<modules>
    <module>Resources</module>
    <module>ResourceTree</module>
    <module>Service</module>
    <module>Transport</module>
<module>Branding</module>
```

properties tag starts here

```
<scl_version>0.0.1</scl_version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
<karaf.deploy.build.folder>${env.KARAF_BASE}/deploy</karaf.deploy.build.folder>
```

property tag ends here

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>code_coverage</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.0.201403182114</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default-instrument</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>instrument</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <jacoco-agent.destfile>target/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-beta-2</version>
    <configuration>
    <flattenMode>ossrh</flattenMode>
    <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <!-- enable flattening -->
      <execution>
        <id>flatten</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>flatten</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <!-- ensure proper cleanup -->
      <execution>
        <id>flatten.clean</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
        <classifier>runtime</classifier>
        <version>0.7.0.201403182114</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

generated flattened pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.a.b</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

property is used in grand grand child pom ( for trail, if successfull without warning, i can iuse it everywhere):

```
<groupId>org.a.b</groupId>
<artifactId>CD<artifactId>
<version>${scl_version}</version>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<name>CD</name>
<description>OSGi bundle project.</description>
```

Apart from this, it has bundle plugin dependency plugin and some dependencies. In flattened pom ofthis child this version is resolved to 0.0.1

Comment: Can you show your pom file? Cause otherwise it's hard to understand what the problem might be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I mailed to developer of this plugin and his response is:

> The warning is coming from Maven, based on *the original* pom.xml
>   Before Maven starts executing, a buildplan is created and the pom.xml
>   is analyzed, causing this warning. The flatten-maven plugin kicks in
>   later in the process generating the flattened pom.xml and making sure
>   that's the file being installed/deployed. Your issue can't be fixed by
>   the flatten-maven-plugin and won't be fixed in Maven Core (the warning
>   is there for a good reason).

So, it answers the question very well.

Comment: +1 for self-help and sharing information from the developer from the plugin !

Comment: Changes made in Maven 3.5.0 to support CI friendly builds: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 0):

So when using a recent maven version, simply rename your property from `scl_version` to `revision` and the warning should go away.